# Can I use nodejs logo as part of my course cover?

Tags: trademark

I'm starting a course about building website backends with NodeJS and I was wondering is it legal to use the [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) logo as **part** of my course cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Node.js Foundation Trademark Guidelines for the Node.js Marks](https://nodejs.org/static/documents/trademark-policy.pdf)

> Q: Can I use the Node.js marks?
>   A: Yes, in accordance with these guidelines

...

> When reasonable, please include this notice when you use a mark outside of the Foundation:
>   Node.js is a trademark of Joyent, Inc. and is used with its permission. We are not endorsed by or affiliated with Joyent.”

...

> You must also request permission to make merchandise with the Node.js for commercial use (if you plan to give away merchanise in connection with an event, we would not consider that to be a commercial use)

...

> Please send your request to trademark@nodejs.org to seek permission for use of Node.js in a publication.